# I need to append a variable without adding (using an arithmatic operator)

Tags: javascript

There's probably a really simple fix to this but I can't quite find any similar questions that give me an answer.

***Javascript***

```
products = [" + Ticket", " + VIP", " + Shirt"];
v_mult = products[0] + par_left + v + par_right;
v_sing = products[0];

if (ticket == 3 & document.getElementById("amount").value <= 1) {
  document.frm.display.value -= v_mult, document.frm.display.value = v_sing;
};

if (ticket == 3 & document.getElementById("amount").value > 1) {
  document.frm.display.value -= v_sing, document.frm.display.value = v_mult;
};

//function for adding vip tickets 
if (ticket == 4 & document.getElementById("amount").value <= 1) {
  document.frm.display.value -= s_mult, document.frm.display.value = s_sing;
};

if (ticket == 4 & document.getElementById("amount").value > 1) {
  document.frm.display.value -= s_sing, document.frm.display.value = s_mult;
};
```

**See, if I just put...**

```
if (ticket == 3 & document.getElementById("amount").value <= 1) {
  document.frm.display.value -= v_mult, document.frm.display.value = v_sing;
};
```

it changes the value of "display" (the textbox) to "Ticket". Which is fine, but it doesn't allow me to append "VIP" to ticket; it only allows me to replace "Ticket" with "VIP".

It's because I'm using "**=** v_mult". I'm sure that's the problem, I just don't have a solution. I want the value to be "Ticket" but I don't want "Ticket" to be erased when I need to add "VIP". "+=" returns "NaN", and "=" just changes  the entire value of "display", instead of editing/appending new values.

Comment: In short, I need the "+" operator to work as an "append" and not a "mathematical operator".

Comment: Your question is clear as mud. There are undeclared variables, variables that aren't defined, and expressions separated by a comma that should be separate statements. It will help greatly if you post a minimal, "working" example that displays the issue.

Comment: I'm fairly sure that you mean `&&` everywhere that you currently have bitwise `&`

Comment: @RobG right, sorry about that. Here is a link to a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/86fhfbr4/

Comment: @DanielJohnson _minimal, "working" example_ I think you missed the __minimal__ part. Besides, this is the same invalid JS just with a bunch of markup and style.

Comment: @RobG basically, when I click "Ticket" it gets highlighted. When I click "Add", a T-shirt and whatever amount is posted at the bottom, gets added into the top long circular display. In my code, "document.frm.display.value = v_sing" is writing "Ticket" in the display, which is what I want it to do. But if I were to add "VIP", "Ticket" would be erased from the display and "VIP" would take its place. It's because of the ".value = v_sing", I'm setting the value of the display = to the variable "v_sing". I don't want to do that, I want to set the value = to whatever is there, plus what I click next

Comment: Where you have `document.frm.display.value -= v_mult`, the `-` operator will convert the operands to Number, so there's a very good chance this isn't doing what you expect as the value of *v_mult* is a string that starts `'+ Ticket'`.

Comment: @RobG EXACTLY!!!! that's the problem. I just need to find a way to, when I click "VIP" keep "+ Ticket" and add "VIP" to the string, rather than replace 
"+ Ticket" with "VIP".

Comment: @DanielJohnson read the SO help docs, specifically [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
document.frm.display.value -= v_mult, document.frm.display.value = v_sing;

document.frm.display.value -= (" + Ticket" + document.frm.display.value = " +  Ticket"
```

> I want the value to be "Ticket" but I don't want "Ticket" to be erased when I need to add "VIP".

I think you want something like this:

val = document.frm.display.value;

document.frm.display.value = (v_mult + val + v_sing);

You may be getting NaN because you are adding strings to numbers with +=

Comment: If you saw in the jsfiddle, when I click "Ticket", "+ Ticket" pops into the top textbox. When I click "VIP",, "+ VIP" pops into the top textbox IN PLACE of "+ Ticket". How do I keep both and just add "+ VIP" to "+ Ticket"? @joatis

Comment: The fiddles not working for me now. I would keep them as separate values and concatenate when you need them and just overwrite whatever the previous value was.

Comment: There is no need for the grouping operator `( )`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `.concat()`

```
newString = string1.concat(string2);
```

Instead of

```
newString = string1 + string2;
```

Comment: How will that make any difference? All the values in the OP appear to be strings, so "+" is already doing concatenation.